# Marker setPosition not working

Tags: google-maps, marker

I have this code

```
var new = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
marker.setPosition(new);
infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
```

and the marker is not moved, but the infowindow is moved

and I have no error in console

10 days ago was working, could be from the 11 may update?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was with latest version

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=
```

before was

```
 <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=...
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Answer (score 1):

you should assign the latitude and longitude to a variable because `new` is just a keyword for instantiating a new position object.

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
marker.setPosition(position);
infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
```